# Ksoap2,android app upload img always return false

Tags: java, web-services, soap, utf-8

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void connectWebService(String imageBuffer) {
    SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    soapObject.addProperty("imei","123456789" );
    soapObject.addProperty("bytestr", imageBuffer);

    //soapObject.addProperty("image", imageBuffer);
    soapObject.addProperty("filename", "my.jpg");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
    envelope.bodyOut = soapObject;

    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
    HttpTransportSE httpTranstation = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        httpTranstation.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        Log.e("connectWebService", result.toString());
        Message msg=handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.obj=result;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("tag",e.toString());

    }
}
public Handler handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        String test=msg.obj.toString();

            tv.setText(test);


    }

};
```

Comment: POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Set_photo"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Set_photo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <imei>string</imei>
      <fileBytes>base64Binary</fileBytes>
      <fileName>string</fileName>
    </Set_photo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post the code (or other things) as a comment  or an answer.

Comment: I see in your code you have set envelope.dotNet = true.That means you have a dot net webserveice at the back end (e.g. WCF).If server returns false every time you should try start debugging server side code first.Better if you can add specific tags (WCF or .Net) to your question and your server side code as well.

Comment: Please post actual error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: ok,thank ,i make some changes now,  soapObject.addProperty("bytestr",uploadBuffer.getBytes());   java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [B@76b37bd

Comment: what"s your meaning?